# MySQL SELECT query that counts left joined rows takes too long

Tags: mysql, optimization

Does anyone know how to optimize this query?

```
SELECT planbook.*,
  COUNT(pb_unit_id) AS total_units,
  COUNT(pb_lsn_id) AS total_lessons
FROM planbook
  LEFT JOIN planbook_unit ON pb_unit_pb_id = pb_id
  LEFT JOIN planbook_lesson ON pb_lsn_pb_id = pb_id
WHERE pb_site_id = 1
GROUP BY pb_id
```

The slow part is getting the total number of matching units and lessons.  I have indexes on the following fields (and others):

- planbook.pb_id
- planbook_unit.pb_unit_pb_id
- planbook_lesson.pb_lsn_pb_id

My only objective is to get the total number of matching units and lessons along with the details of each planbook row.

However, this query is taking around 35 seconds.  I have 1625 records in planbook, 13,693 records in planbook_unit, and 122,950 records in planbook_lesson.

Any suggestions?

**Edit: Explain Results**

[image: Explain results]

Comment: Can you show us the result of the `explain` statement?

Comment: If planbook_unit and planbook_lesson are independent of one another, you'll end up getting the cross product of them for each planbook and your counts will be wrong. When data from indirectly related 1:N relationships is needed, subqueries are almost always required.

Comment: I just edited it to show the Explain results.  How would I best set up subqueries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  planbook.*,
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM planbook_unit
               WHERE pb_unit_pb_id = planbook.pb_id ) AS total_units,
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM planbook_lesson
               WHERE pb_lsn_pb_id  = planbook.pb_id ) AS total_lessons
    FROM  planbook
    WHERE  pb_site_id = 1

planbook:        INDEX(pb_site_id)
planbook_unit:   INDEX(pb_unit_pb_id)
planbook_lesson: INDEX(pb_lsn_pb_id)
```

Comment: That worked like a charm!  Query down from 35 seconds to 0.2 seconds.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looking to your query

You should  add and index  for

```
table planbook column pb_site_id
```

and eventually a composite one  for

```
table planbook column (pb_site_id, pd_id)
```

Comment: I'm guessing he is grouping on planbook's PK, so it should not cause predictability issues (pretty sure this use case is exactly why MySQL even allowed it to begin with).

Comment: Not saying MySQL hasn't deprecated whether it was allowed, it has and server installs default to disallowing it now; just saying I am pretty sure this is why it ever was. It's convenient, but evidently not worth the headaches when someone unintentionally uses it.

Comment: I already have an index on pb_site_id and primary key pb_id.  Is it helpful/necessary to set up composite indexes or does MySQL find those efficiencies on its own?

Comment: @LStarky - MySQL does not get smart about indexes, at least not in that way.  There are 2 auto-generated indexes:  (1) for `FOREIGN KEYs`; (2) for derived tables.  (Neither of those apply here.)